# String search and replace Java

Tags: java, search, hashset, string-search

I am dealing with an algorithm approach to finding keywords into my string. I have a HashSet contains almost 1 million keys in it and I want to replace all of these keys with blank into my sentences. My problem is this, when i have 1000 sentences with 10 word in it, it will become 10.000 words totally. 
What is the best approach to search keywords into sentences here?

```
    Set<String> keywords;//1.000.000 entry
    for(int i =0;i<textModel.length;i++){//1.000 entry almost
            String[] splitted = textModel[i].getText().split(" ");
            for (int j = 0; j < splitted.length; j++) {
                if(keywords.contains(splitted[j]){//?
                     splitted[j] = "";// ??
                }
            }
        }
```

Is this approach OK? or should i use an text search algorithm for it?

Comment: Can you assure that the keywords should match only whole words. Your algorithm will not find subwords and overlapping matches. If this is acceptable your algorithm is quite fast.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you're really worried about time in your search you should use the Boyer-Moore algorithm.When there are mismatches the algorithm skips over X amount of characters/words in your case.
[image]

But it allows for something called the Good suffix rule where a portion of a word is found and that portion that parallels with another substring aligns until it finds a pair.
[image]

But if time isn't an issue, your algorithm should be good.

Comment: Boyer-Moore is not fitting for a set of on million keywords to search for. One should better consider an indexed search or the Aho-Corasick-Algorithm.